# UWP DownloadsFolder.CreateFolderAsync problem

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp

If I use the below code in my Xamarin Forms UWP application:

StorageFile newFile = await DownloadsFolder.CreateFileAsync("MyFile.txt", CreationCollisionOption.FailIfExists);

I get a file created in the 'Downloads\MyAppName' folder. ('Downloads\MyAppName\MyFile.txt')
If I use the below code to create a folder:

await DownloadsFolder.CreateFolderAsync("MyAppName", CreationCollisionOption.FailIfExists);
I get 'Downloads\MyAppName\MyAppName'

How do I create the 'Downloads\MyAppName' without having to create a file in the folder?

The actual folder path in explorer is:
C:\Users\Lenovo\Downloads\54367MyAppName.MyAppName_7prw090s3s9b7!App

Any help appreciated.
Thanks
Paul.

Comment: You mean that you want to create new folder in downloads folder, but I get the default DownloadsFolder path is :C:\Users\cherryb\Downloads\xxxxxxx!App, you want to delete xxxxxxx!App folder in Downloads folder?

Comment: The 'MyAppName' folder is created by default in the 'Downloads' folder when CreateFileAsync is used. (Downloads\MyAppName). If I only try to create a folder using CreateFolderAsync I get ('Downloads\MyAppName\FolderToCreateName'). I just want 'Downloads\MyAppName' to be created withouthaving to create a file as well. Thanks Paul.

Comment: Actually, "MyAppName" and "54367MyAppName.MyAppName_7prw090s3s9b7!App", it does not affect your storage.